# Accessing a method of the Outer Class inside a static Inner Class

Tags: java, android

This is a snippet from accessing Google APIs:

```
/* Called from ErrorDialogFragment when the dialog is dismissed. */
public void onDialogDismissed() {
    mResolvingError = false;
}

/* A fragment to display an error dialog */
public static class ErrorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    public ErrorDialogFragment() { }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Get the error code and retrieve the appropriate dialog
        int errorCode = this.getArguments().getInt(DIALOG_ERROR);
        return GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(errorCode,
                this.getActivity(), REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).onDialogDismissed();
    }
}
```

While this works if the code is in an activity, how do you get `onDialogDismissed()` a fragment to use it inside the static fragment class

I tried it with this, doesn't seem to work:

```
 @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        ErrorDialogFragment innerClass = new OuterFragment.ErrorDialogFragment();

    innerClass.onDialogDismissed(); // Still cant find the method of the outer class
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ErrorDialogFragment` is a `static` (inner) class and being such, it *directly* accesses everything from the **static** context of the outer class.

The method `onDialogDismissed();` is not part of the `static` context of the outer class (i.e. it is not `static`) and this is why it's not directly accessible from the inner class.

In order to access it, you need an instance of the outer class. Probably, the `getActivity()` method provides such instance, which is the reason it works in that case.

Comment: Now i understood why. I also used this `((OuterClass) getParentFragment()).onDialogDismissed();` Since it is nested inside a fragment.

Answer (score 2):

Use `context`. Whenever you call the outer class just pass the context. 
Then you can use Context to `dismiss` the dialog.

try:

```
 context..onDialogDismissed();
```

Comment: Just wondering: where is `context` coming from? Is that part of that class from Google?

Comment: Context comes from the Activity.

Answer (score 1):

`onDialogDismissed()` is not a method  of `ErrorDialogFragment`, so this can't work:

```
ErrorDialogFragment innerClass = new OuterFragment.ErrorDialogFragment();
innerClass.onDialogDismissed();
```

What you can do is using `OuterClass.this` in order to access members and methods of the outer class, e.g.:

```
@Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    OuterClass.this.onDialogDismissed();
}
```

If you use only `onDialogDismissed()` the compiler assumes the method to be in the `ErrorDialogFragment` class.

However, this will lead to the next issue that `onDialogDismissed()` is not a `static` method - as *kocko* pointed out correctly.